# Sending cmd and receiving output using java

Tags: java, shell, process, bufferedreader, bufferedwriter

I'm basically making a shell for fun to play around with sending and receiving things to command prompt. I'm running into a bit of an issue though. Here is the code I have for my command line:

```
public class CommandLine {
    private Process cmdProcess;
    private BufferedReader reader;
    private BufferedWriter writer;
    private StringBuffer bf;
    private String ls = System.getProperty("line.separator");

public CommandLine() {
}

public void connect(){
    try{
        cmdProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /b start");
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(cmdProcess.getInputStream()));
        writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(cmdProcess.getOutputStream()));
        bf = new StringBuffer();
    } catch(Exception e){ }
}

public void sendCommand(String command){
    try {
        writer.write(command + ls);
        writer.flush();
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void getContent(){
    String s;
    while((s = readResponse()) != null){
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}

public String readResponse(){
    try{
        return reader.readLine();
    } catch(Exception e){
        return null;
    }
}

public void disconnect(){
    try{
        sendCommand("quit");
        reader.close();
        writer.close();
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void reset(){
    try {
        reader.reset();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Here is the problem though. When I'm in my main method and I do something like:

```
public static void main(String [] args){
    CommandLine cmd = new CommandLine();
    cmd.connect();
    cmd.sendCommand("dir");
    cmd.getContent();
    System.out.println("Here");
}
```

"Here" never gets printed. So I'm curious what it is that I did wrong. Also I want to be able to send a command and then only read THAT response back. I was thinking maybe I could do so with reset() on the reader but I am not sure. If that was not clear enough, I mean I don't want the response to just be appended to a StringBuffer or anything like that.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Read the response from a running process will not finish as it's not reached the EOF...

Comment: Is there a way to make it so I can read responses and have them finish?

Comment: Making a command shell is way more complicated than what you're trying to do.  Your best bet is to start and cmd process, include your command (dir), and finish the cmd process, so you can get the output from the process.  You will only be able to process one command at a time.

Comment: I know making a shell is difficult. I've done a lot with java, I've just never been exposed to creating a shell. I figured I would give it a shot as a side project. If you could lead me on the right path that would be great. Not asking for code or anything, just a place to start. Whether it be using Socket connections instead or going about it completely differently

Answer (score 0):

You can use existing library for command line executing: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/tutorial.html